# RTCRecorder: TypeError Recorder is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to record wav from the browser via a React app and send it to my nodeJS API. This was working fine in a prototype html5 example. But now I'm moving it to React/Typescript. I'm pretty new to typescript, so everything feels a little hacky.

I'm using RecordRTC, code so far is:

declaration file because recordRTC doesnt have a @types/recordrtc:

```
declare module "recordrtc";
```

Actual code:

```
startRecording() {
        this.record = true
        this.captureUserMedia((stream: any) => {
            this.recordAudio = RecordRTC(stream, { recorderType: 'StereoAudioRecorder', type: 'audio', mimeType: 'audio/wav' });
            this.recordAudio.startRecording();
        });
    }
```

And when I call startRecording, I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Recorder is not a constructor
    at initRecorder (RecordRTC.js:87)
    at Object.startRecording (RecordRTC.js:70)
    at PracticeScreen.tsx:143
```

And what shows up in the chrome browser is:

[image]
I'm guessing its something to do with the .d.ts file but I dont even know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The RecordRTC documentation](https://recordrtc.org/RecordRTC.html) shows that `recorderType` expects a class constructor, but your example is setting it to a string. You can set it to the class constructor for [StereoAudioRecorder](https://recordrtc.org/StereoAudioRecorder.html) like this:

```
RecordRTC(
  stream, 
  { 
    recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,   // <-------- class constructor not string 
    type: 'audio', 
    mimeType: 'audio/wav' 
  },
);
```

Comment: Ah you're a saint and a scholar. Had no idea how I missed that. But for anyone who this is still throwing errors for:

You have to of course import StereoAudioRecorder from the package, and you have to set `recorderType: new StereoAudioRecorder`